# How to read nested JSONs for aggregations?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark.
All I want to do is, read nested jsons and group them based on a certain condition. 
For example: If the json contains details of a person like his city and zipcode. I would want to group the people who belong the same city and zipcode.

I have progressed till reading the jsons into DataSet.
But I am not knowing how to group them.

My Nested JSON format is

```
{
  "entity": {
    "name": "SJ",
    "id": 31
  },
  "hierarchy": {
    "state": "TN",
    "city": "CBE"
  },
  "data": {}}
```

This is the code I have written to read the nested json from file.

```
public void groupJsonString(SparkSession spark) {
    Dataset<Row> studentRecordDS = spark.read()
            .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
            .json("/home/shiney/Documents/NGA/sparkJsonFiles/*.json");
    StructType st = studentRecordDS.schema();


    List<StructType> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(StructField field : st.fields()) {
        nestedList.add((StructType)field.dataType());
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `spark.read.json` (as you did) followed by "flatten" operator in `select`.

(I use Scala and leaving converting to Java as your home exercise :))

Let's use the sample of yours.

```
$ cat ../datasets/sample.json
{
  "entity": {
    "name": "SJ",
    "id": 31
  },
  "hierarchy": {
    "state": "TN",
    "city": "CBE"
  },
  "data": {}
}
```

The code could be as follows (again it's Scala).

```
val entities = spark
  .read
  .option("multiLine", true)
  .json("../datasets/sample.json")
scala> entities.printSchema
root
 |-- entity: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hierarchy: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

Let's flatten `entity` and `hierarchy` top-level columns.

```
scala> entities.select("entity.*", "hierarchy.*").show
+---+----+----+-----+
| id|name|city|state|
+---+----+----+-----+
| 31|  SJ| CBE|   TN|
+---+----+----+-----+
```

Aggregation should be a no-brainer now.